# jquery jScrollPane too small viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, jquery-jscrollpane

I've some problem using a plugin of jQuery called [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html). At the moment it has a weird behaviour. It just doesn't read the whole height of the contained table. The html stucture is the following:

```
<div id="container-of-the-table">
<table></table>
</div>
```

The javascript is the following:

```
setupScrollPane('#container-of-the-table');

function setupScrollPane(el, options) {
    var id = (el instanceof jQuery) ? el.attr("id") : el.substring(1);
    api = $(el).jScrollPane({
        horizontalGutter: 6,
        verticalGutter: 6,
        mouseWheelSpeed: 50
    }).data("jsp");
    scrollPaneApi[id] = api;

    if (undefined != options){
        if (undefined != options.scrollToX){
            api.scrollToX (options.scrollToX);
        }
        if (undefined != options.scrollToY){
            api.scrollToY (options.scrollToY);
        }
    }
}
```

The css is the following:

```
table {
    display: block;
    height: 165px;
    width: 1080px;
}
#container-of-the-table{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The content of the table is more than 1000px but the shown content (with a minimal scrollbar in the right css for the plugin) is less than 200px.

The plugin seem to be working but its not cause it lets me scroll only a minimal part of the table.

I've found a [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jscrollpane/OFR20pto6xI) with a similar problem but i couldn't understand how it's solved.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the css of the container? Maybe adding `height: auto; max-height: 165px` could solve the issue.

Comment: Yes this was the right thing to do!!!

Comment: Nice glad to hear that! I am going to post the answer with this solution then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently to solve this issue, you have to modify the css of `#container-of-the-table`. This is the right code:

```
#container-of-the-table{
    overflow:auto;
    max-height: 165px;
    height: auto;
}
```

I am glad that my answer was helpful!